# how to clone/copy an excel worksheet and have it removed on second run using apache poi and java

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
XSSFSheet wire_drawing = (XSSFSheet) wb.getSheetAt(0);
            XSSFRow r1 = wire_drawing.getRow(3);
            XSSFCell c1 = r1.getCell(8);
            c1.setCellValue(wd);
            NoOfTickects(n1,"0");

            XSSFRow row5 = wire_drawing.getRow(3);
            XSSFCell cell4 = row5.getCell(4);
            cell4.setCellValue("2/"+ diameter + "mm HD");

            XSSFSheet stranding = (XSSFSheet) wb.getSheetAt(1);
            XSSFRow r2 = stranding.getRow(2);
            XSSFCell c2 = r2.getCell(10);
            c2.setCellValue(bs);
            NoOfTickects(n2,"1");
```

this is my code to insert data on an excel sheet. i am using the NoOfTickets() method to clone the worksheets and is defined as follows:

```
 public void NoOfTickects(int no, String sheet_index){

            switch(sheet_index){
                case "0" :
                     if(no==2){
                         wb.cloneSheet(0);
                        }
                     else {
                         for(int i =0 ; i<no ; i=i+2){
                             wb.cloneSheet(0);
                         }
                     }
                break;
                case "1" :
                     if(no==2){
                         wb.cloneSheet(1);
                        }
                     else {
                         for(int i =0 ; i<no ; i=i+2){
                             wb.cloneSheet(1);
                         }
                     }
                break;
                case "2" :
                     if(no==2){
                         wb.cloneSheet(2);
                        }
                     else {
                         for(int i =0 ; i<no ; i=i+2){
                             wb.cloneSheet(2);
                         }
                     }
                break;
```

the variable "no" is the number of worksheets required. originally, the worksheet looks like

[the initial worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMIS2.jpg)

after running the code the worksheet will be

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhiMA.jpg)

as you can see at the bottom of the second worksheet, the sheets are now more than five. How can I remove the extra worksheets so that the next time i run the code the extra sheets will be appended to the first five worksheets only?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int rowq = 8; rowq < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); rowq++) {
                wb.removeSheetAt(rowq);
            }
```

i found a solution above. just in case someone else will face the same challenge